Uploading image using API but getting broken image each time
I'm using this class to make an API call:
@Path("uploads")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UploadResource extends BaseResource {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
    private static final int IMAGE_SIZE_LIMIT = 2000000;
    private static final int PDF_SIZE_LIMIT = 5000000;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UploadResource.class);

    private String imageExtension(String type) {
        switch (type) {
            case "image/jpeg":
                return "jpg";
            case "image/png":
                return "png";
            case "image/gif":
                return "gif";
            case "image/webp":
                return "webp";
            case "image/svg+xml":
                return "svg";
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported image type");
        }
    }

    @Path("{entity}/{id}")
    @POST
    @Consumes("image/*")
    public Response uploadImage(@PathParam("entity") String entity, @PathParam("id") long entityId, File file,
                                @HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE) String type) {
        try {
            // Extract the file extension from the content type
            String extension = type.substring("image/".length());
            String name = entityId + "_" + new Date().getTime();

            // Ensure correct buffer size and image size limit handling
            try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
                 OutputStream output = Context.getMediaManager().createFileStream(entity, name, extension)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // Use 8 KB buffer
                int read;
                long transferred = 0;
                
                // Read in chunks and write to output
                while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    transferred += read;

                    // Check if the image size exceeds the limit
                    if (transferred > IMAGE_SIZE_LIMIT) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Image size limit exceeded"+transferred);
                    }
                }
                output.flush(); // Ensure all data is written
            }

            // Return successful response with the generated image file name
            Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
            result.put("image", name + "." + extension);
            return Response.ok(ResponseHelper.getResultWith_200(result)).build();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.warn("Image upload failed (LS): ", ex); // Log the entire exception stack trace
            return Response.ok(ResponseHelper.getResultWith_400(ResponseHelper.formatMsg(ex.getMessage()))).build();
        }
    }
}

and below is my MediaManager:
public class MediaManager {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MediaManager.class);

    private final String path;

    public MediaManager(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    private File createFile(String uniqueId, String name) throws IOException {
        Path filePath = Paths.get(path, uniqueId, name);
        Path directoryPath = filePath.getParent();
        if (directoryPath != null) {
            Files.createDirectories(directoryPath);
        }
        LOGGER.info("Creating file at path: {}", filePath);
        return filePath.toFile();
    }

    public OutputStream createFileStream(String uniqueId, String name, String extension) throws IOException {
        File file = createFile(uniqueId, name + "." + extension);
        LOGGER.info("Opening output stream for file: {}", file.getAbsolutePath());
        return new FileOutputStream(file);
    }
}

Each time I upload an image (no matter if it's a .png/.jpeg/.jpg) from postman using binary selection in body or form-data,
an empty image is created with the correct name, directory and size e.g., 502kb instead of 0kb. However, the image is broken and I'm unable to open it using any image viewer. What am I doing wrong?

Try use MULTIPART_FORM_DATA and FormDataParam instead PathParam implementation, like this code:
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/endpoint_name")
public Response uploadImage(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
                           @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader,
                           @FormDataParam("id") long id,
                           @FormDataParam("entity") String entity,
                           @HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE) String type){

        // Extract the file extension from the content type
        String extension = type.substring("image/".length());
        String name = entityId + "_" + new Date().getTime();

       //save file in tomcat temporary directory
       File file = File.createTempFile(name, "."+extension);
       Files.copy(fileInputStream, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
       
       //...
       //...
}

